# Owner of nested class object

Tags: c++, c++11, nested-class

In C++/C++11, how can I get a reference/pointer to the "owner" of a nested class instantiation? For example:

```
class A
{
public:
    friend class B;
    class B
    {
    public:
        Foo bar(int i) { return get_owner().x[...]; }

    private:
        A& get_owner()
        { // How to do this? Pseudo code:
            return (A*)(this - offsetof(A, b));
        }
    };

    B b;
};
```

Note: In my case, A is *not* a [standard layout type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout), because it has private and public member variables.

Background: I'd like to implement "zero cost" syntactic sugar for complex properties, which access the data structures in the owning class and which allow users of A to write, e.g.,

```
A a;
...
x = a.nodes[5];
y = a.nodes.size();
for (auto n: a.nodes)  // using a.nodes.begin() and a.nodes.end()
    ...
```

Note 2: I could probably do this using dirty tricks, but is there a portable, standards-compliant way to do this?
If not, I'll have to implement B so that I can write "a.nodes(5)" and "for (auto n: a.nodes())", but that looks rather ugly.

Edit: I already thought about giving B a reference to A, but then I couldn't use the default copy/move constructor/assignment operator for A. This wouldn't be so bad in my case, but I'm curious whether there's another solution.

Comment: I'm afraid declaring a nested class, doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Classes defined one inside another have no relation between them. It's pretty much the same as a class inside a namespace.

Comment: You cannot do this in C++, because classes nested inside other classes do not have references of their outer classes. An outer class to an inner class is more a namespace than an owner.

Comment: @user1233963 In C++11, there is *somewhat* of relation between `A` and `A::B`, in that `A::B` is considered a *member* of `A` and has therefore access to private members of `A`.

Comment: @Oswald: doesn't look like that's true http://ideone.com/ntsSnO

Comment: @g-makulik: Actually, I know pretty well what declaring a nested class means, and that it's not the same as a non-static nested class in Java. That doesn't mean that there exists no solution.

Comment: From what I understand you're trying to implement C#-like properties, is that correct ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I know, but a *member* of an object has a relationship to its *surrounding object*, even if that relationship can't be used directly.

Comment: @user1233963: Something like C#-properties, yes.

Comment: @AdrianWillenbücher: perhaps you'd like to have a look some other implementations: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/640013/Cplusplus11-Properties and my own one https://github.com/R3AL/cpProperty

Comment: @user1233963 http://ideone.com/ntsSnO says that `A::B::B()` cannot be accessed because it is private. When you have solved this problem, then you can construct a `A::B` and the constuctor can access the private `A::tmp` member of the `A` that you pass into the constructor.

Comment: @Oswald: A::B::B() is not private.

Comment: @user1233963 Yes it is. The C++ standard says so (in light of a missing class access modifier) and the error message says so as well.

Comment: Damn, I must be blind. You are indeed correct

Comment: I thought a nested class is automatically a friend?

Comment: @NeilKirk It is. When I declare that you are my friend, then you are allowed to do things to me that I do not allow others to do; at least if we were C++ classes. In real life, you would automatically be obliged to help me move or to pick me up after a long night at the bar. C++ has a more selfless notion of friendship.

Answer (score 3):

Add a member to `B`, that points to the owner.

Comment: that would not be the "zero cost" the OP wants

Comment: @ArneMertz True, but such a zero-cost solution doesn't exist.

Comment: That was actually the first solution I considered, but then I couldn't use the default copy constructor and assignment operator. Admittedly, that's a small price to pay, but I'm curious whether there exists another solution.

Comment: The solution that you envisioned in your pseudo code requires that the assignement operator and all constructors of `A::B` are private, to make sure that a `B` does not exist outside the `A` that created it. Particularly, you cannot use the default copy constructor and assignment operator either (well, in C++11 you can, but you have to explicitly declare that you want that).

Comment: I don't care if someone would be stupid enough to instantiate A::B outside of A, so I'd leave the special member functions of A::B default and public.  Therefore, I don't see why I couldn't use the default copy/move constructor/assignment operator of A in the solution I envisioned.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that every instance of class `A` has a member of class `B` is not something that class `B` is aware of.

The only way to create a mapping from `B` to `A` is to *create one*. Yourself. No such mapping exists, because not every `B` instance is *required* to be associated with an `A` instance. Only those instances created as part of `A` are, and there is no way for `B` to know whether it's part of `A`.

Not unless you tell it, of course. And that's going to require storing per-`B`-object state; `B` will have to store a pointer/reference to the `A` to which it is a member.

> Background: I'd like to implement "zero cost" syntactic sugar for complex properties, which access the data structures in the owning class and which allow users of A to write, e.g.,

That is not possible in C++; best give up on it now. Even if `B` were *empty*, there's no requirement that they wouldn't take up space in `A`. Indeed, there is a requirement that they *will* take up space in `A`. Every member of a class instance has an address, and no two members are allowed to have the *same* address. The empty-base-optimization only works for *base classes*, not members.

So being "zero cost" is not possible. Since `B` instances are going to have to take up space in `A`, you may as well put that space to good use by storing a pointer/reference to a member of `A`.